# How do I not print the multiplication sign at the end of the factorial expression for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, format

I created a program in java that takes an int as an input and prints its factorial. For example input = 5 printed: 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120. However, I can't find a way to get rid of the multiplication sign at the end of it. I get: 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 x = 120. What can I do to get rid of it only at the end? Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Factorial {
public static void factorial(int input)
{
    int sum = 1;
    for(int i = input; i>=1; i--)
    {
        System.out.print(i+" x ");
        sum *= i;

    }
    System.out.print(" = " + sum);
}

public static void main (String []args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number to obtain its factorial");
    int a = in.nextInt();
    factorial(a);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you're at the last loop cycle, that is, if `i` is equal to 1. Then you know you're at the last number and you don't need to print the x.

You can do it like this :

```
System.out.print(i);
if(i != 1) {
    System.out.print(" x ");
}
```

or like this if you prefer only one line, using what is called a ternary operator:

```
System.out.print((i != 1) ? i + " x " : i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop

```
if (i == 1) {
    System.out.print(i);
} else {
    System.out.print(i + " x ");
}
```

However, you are not considering when the user enters 0 or a negative number. So you can use this instead:

```
public static void factorial(int input)
{
    if (input < 0) {
        System.out.println("Input should be positive");
        return;
    }

    if (input == 0) {
        System.out.print("0! = 1" );
        return;
    }

    int factorial = 1;

    for(int i = input; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (i == 1) {
            System.out.print(i);
        } else {
            System.out.print(i + " x ");
        }
        factorial *= i;

    }

    System.out.print(" = " + factorial);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
     import java.util.*;
     public class Factorial {
     public static void factorial(int input)
     {
     int sum = 1;
     for(int i = input; i>=1; i--)
     {
     System.out.print(i);

     if(i > 1) {
     System.out.print(" x ");
     sum *=i;
     }

     }
     System.out.print(" = " + sum);
     }

     public static void main (String []args)
     {
     Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a number to obtain its factorial");
     int a = in.nextInt();
     factorial(a);

     }
     }
```

where the system only outputs "X" if i is greater than 1

```
       if(i > 1) {
     System.out.print(" x ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no practical purpose in multiplying by 1.  So I changed the condition to end when input == 1 and then move the 1 to the System.out.print.
This will save you several lines of code execution.

```
for(int i = input; i> 1; i--)
{
    System.out.print(i+" x ");
    sum *= i;

}
System.out.print("1 = " + sum);
```